# Add Title to Kendo UI Grid Toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui

I am looking to add a title to the Kendo UI grid toolbar and align it left. Is there some way I can add an h2 or h3 to this area?

Also to style just this toolbar can I access the style property? ( I want to put a darker color/gradient to the top and bottom (where pagination is))

```
toolbar   : [
        {"name": "create", template: "<img class='k-grid-add' src='add.png'/>"},
        {"name": "save", template: "<img class='k-grid-save-changes' src='save.png'/>"},
        {"name": "cancel", template: "<img class='k-grid-cancel-changes' src='cancel.png'/>"}
    ],
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class that identifies the Kendo Grid toolbar is `k-grid-toolbar`. So for styling it, you might use:

```
#grid .k-grid-toolbar { 
    background: red;
}
```

For adding some content to the toolbar, you can use:

```
$(".k-grid-toolbar", "#grid").prepend("<h1>hello</h1>");
```

or

```
$(".k-grid-toolbar", "#grid").before("<h1>hello</h1>");
$(".k-grid-toolbar", "#grid").after("<h1>hello</h1>");
```

depending if you want to add the HTML inside the `div` containing the buttons *before* or *after* it.

And `grid` is the `id` of the `div` containing the `grid`.

Comment: Great, so glad for your help OnaBai!

Comment: i know this is an old post OnaBai, but that peace of code is not working with me. I´m doing exactly has you say.

Comment: i just don´t understand what is the problem with my code, i have a div in my project which has the necessary div for kendo to open a listview. So, it´s like, the mother div and inside the #grid like in your example, then i´m calling it with the code you showed us. My mother div fades in with the listview inside it, and my toolbar show´s my create button but then the rest of the toolbar is empty.Can you help me?

Comment: @Japa, submit a new question in Stack Overflow and include a code that reproduces what you see in JSFiddle/JSBin/KendoUI Dojo/... and I'll take a look into it

Comment: i have posted the question OnaBai, thansk for helping me, could you check it out?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498234/add-title-to-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: How can you then clear that content if you want to reset the header after refreshing the data?

Comment: @Mike, of course you can. There are multiple way of achieving this: can hide HTML element that you added using `prepend` by adding attribute `display: none` or you can actually remove it using `remove()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Kendo-MVC parlance, the solution is quite simple:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyGridsViewModel>()
    .Name("MyGridsName")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template("<h4>My Grid's Title</h4>"))
    .DataSource(datasource => ...
```

This works fine until you start getting crazy and attempt to use the Create/Custom buttons builders with the toolbar lambda.

In that case, the buttons are never rendered.  The solution there is to use one of the other approaches identified in this thread:  http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-command-button-in-toolbars