# Add title to kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After researching on the web, i´m facing a problem on adding a title into my grid, so my code is:

**.html file:**

```html
<div id="idGridTiposQuartos" class="gridtiposquartos js-var-grid-tipos-quartos"> 
    <div id="gridTiposQuartos">
    </div>
</div>
```

**.js file:**

```js
$("#idBtnTiposQuarto").click(function()
    {
      $("#idGridTiposQuartos").fadeIn(1000);
      $("#idBtnQuartos").attr("disabled", false);
      $(".k-grid-toolbar", "#gridTiposQuartos").before("<h1>hello</h1>");
      $(".k-grid-toolbar", "#gridTiposQuartos").after("<h1>hello</h1>");

(some more code)

$("#gridTiposQuartos").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,   
        pageable: 
        {
          messages: 
          {
            display: "{0} - {1} / {2} items", 
            empty: "0 items",
            page: "Page",
            of: "of {0}", //{0} is total amount of pages
            itemsPerPage: "items per page",
            first: "Go to the first page",
            previous: "Go to the previous page",
            next: "Go to the next page",
            last: "Go to the last page",
            refresh: "Refresh"
          }
        },

        serverPaging: true,
        height: 460,
        
        toolbar:[{name: "create",text: $varGridQuartosBtnNovoPT},{name: "close",text: "X"}],
        
        columns:[{ field:"Nome", title: "Nome" },{ field: "Preco", title:"Preço", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
        
        {command:[{ name: "edit",text:{edit:$varGridQuartosBtnEditarPT,update:$varGridQuartosBtnActualizarPT,cancel:$varGridQuartosBtnCancelarPT}},{ name: "destroy",text:$varGridQuartosBtnApagarPT }],title:"&nbsp;",width: "230px"}],
        
         editable  : {mode : "popup",
             
           window : {title: "Editar",}
(the rest of the code)
```

I think i have posted the necessary code to show my problem, so my question is, what am i missing here?. any help? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `$("#idBtnTiposQuarto")` button when you bind click event?

Comment: yes, in fact, that button fades in the div which has the gird inside.

Comment: ok, it´s working, more or less, i realize this only works if it is binded with a click event, but there is two problems. The first one is, the first time the page loads and i call the grid, nothing happens, but if i close the grid and call it again, then the hello word appears...huh?!?. The second problem is, it reapeats the word and i just want the tile to appear once.

Comment: what does "close / call the grid" mean? add the code

Comment: close means clicking on the X button wich fades out the grid. Call means when i click in the $("#idBtnTiposQuarto"), which fades in the div. Meanwhile i manage to show the tilte, but now it´s always repeating the title, the code i used was(with credits to OnaBai): $(".k-grid-toolbar","#gridTiposQuartos").prepend("<h1>hello</h1>");. So everytime i show the grid but clicking in the idBtnTiposQuarto, the title is added again and again.

Comment: For anyone that is facing the same problem, i did this with the help of @neil in the chat(credits for you): $(".k-grid-toolbar","#gridTiposQuartos:not(:has(h1))").prepend("<h1>hello</h1>"); this peace of code adds the title and also just once!.